# gnome control center: system settings -> details -> graphics. string from command line

Tags: drivers, graphics

Using 12.04 LTS for example:

Where is the string pulled from that the gnome control center displays for:

- System Settings -> Details -> Overview (for the Graphics string)
  or
- System Settings -> Details -> Graphics (for the Driver string)

I would like to pull it up in a command line, but more importantly I am curious where this information is reported from.

---

Update:

Anyhow, I am aware of the glxinfo string. I am trying to troubleshoot AMD unsupported hardware logo for a system that once did have the same 13.1 legacy driver installed on 12.04. The result for glxinfo is: OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 3650 AGP yet the driver information displayed by the control center is: simply: VESA. Clearly the control center is pulling a string for a different case than what glxinfo uses. I will look more closely at the function to see what those cases are. The reason I want to know this is to get a better understanding of the various driver stacks and how information is being pulled from them.

Answer (score 0):

The information is provided by the driver via OpenGL (see [the function being called](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/info/cc-info-panel.c#n297)). If you want, you can use the `glxinfo` command (from `mesa-utils`):

```
$ glxinfo | grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 670MX/PCIe/SSE2
```

[image]